# Why does this not unify? (Prolog)

Tags: prolog, unification

I'm writing a proof-checker for natural deduction, and I'm having a problem with parts of the proof that go "one step further" down the list.

First I read a file etc, and then I call the function that is causing trouble:

```
validate([q],[[1, q, premise],[[2, p, assumption],[3, q, copy(1)]], 
[4, imp(p,q), impint(2,3)]].
```

From checking with trace I know that the call below is the one that fails:

```
validate([[1, q, premise], q], [[[2, p, assumption], [3, q, copy(1)]], [4, imp(p, q), impint(2, 3)]])
```

These are the relevant parts of the program:

```
%% Premise, this is what should unify at the first call %%
validate(Prems,[[N,Y,premise]|T]):-
   member(Y,Prems),
   validate([[N,Y,premise]|Prems],T).

%% This is not being called at the moment, so feel free to ignore it, since it's the next step.%%
%%Box, or the deeper level. This should be called from the sentance above%%
validate(Prems, [[[N,X,assumtion]|BT]|Tail]):-
  reverse([[[N,X,assumtion]|BT]|Tail], RevBox),
  RevBox = [[M,Goal,X]|_], 
  write('1'),
  validate([[N,X,assumtion]|Prems],BT),
  write('2'),
  validate([[X,Goal, box(N,M)]|Tail]).

%%impint%%
validate(Prems, [[N,imp(P,Q),impint(A,B)]|T]):-
 member([P,Q,box(A,B)],Prems),
 write('3'),
 validate([[N,imp(P,Q),impint(A,B)]|Prems],T).

%% copy %%
validate(Prems,[[_,X,copy(A)]|T]):-
 member([A,X,_],Prems),
 validate([[_,X,copy(A)]|Prems],T).
```

Comment: Sometimes its validate/1 sometimes validate/2. I think you have to shown the entire program. You ask why doesn;t this `[...]` unify with `validate(_,_)`. What do you mean?

Comment: Did you try running a `trace`? It's not that it fails to match a clause to start out. It fails to match on the first recursive call.

Comment: @false I added the code that might be called, and fixed the last line.

Comment: @mbratch Yes, I did, and I saw that the call at the top of the question is the one that's failing. I want it to/think it should match validate(Prems,[[N,Y,premise]|T]), but it doesn't.

Comment: It does match that clause. The subsequent recursive call mismatches.

Comment: @mbratch You are right, it seems like I can't interpret the trace properly. So it's the call validate([[1, q, premise], q], [[[2, p, assumption], [3, q, copy(1)]], [4, imp(p, q), impint(2, 3)]]) that fails then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it got pointed out that it wasn't the first but the subsequent call to validate that failed I could trace it to a misspelling of the word 'assumption'.